# Failing to Show Modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I adapting my code to improve the way that modals are displayed, so that in the future I can change the colour (primary, warning, danger, etc.) of my modal to improve the visuals of my website. My modal worked previously, however when I removed the main modal div and placed it into my JS that displays the modals so that it's classes can be easily changed depending on what's meant to be displayed in the modal, it stopped working. The screen fades out, however the modal box does not show. Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can fix this? I have tried various things myself, but I cannot find any open tags or any obvious causes of this issue. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<!-- Modals Containers -->
<div id="mdlGeneral"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#mdlGeneral").html('<div class="modal modal-danger fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">'+Username+' - Ban User</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p>Are you sure you wish to suspend <strong>'+Username+'</strong> from the Cadet Portal?</p><div id="divBanUserError"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="BanUser(\''+Username+'\',\''+Page+'\')">Yes</button></div></div></div></div>');
$("#mdlGeneral").modal("show");
```

Comment: mdlGeneral is not a modal. The div within it is. Therefore you have to call the modal command on that inner div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using bootstrap or a similar library, you should add the modal class to the top element, ie :

```
<div id="mdlGeneral" class="modal modal-danger fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
```

Then, in JS,

```
$("#mdlGeneral").html('<div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">'+Username+' - Ban User</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p>Are you sure you wish to suspend <strong>'+Username+'</strong> from the Cadet Portal?</p><div id="divBanUserError"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="BanUser(\''+Username+'\',\''+Page+'\')">Yes</button></div></div></div>');
$("#mdlGeneral").modal("show");
```

If you want to change the class, jQuery also has `.addClass() and removeClass()` methods.

Edit :

Another way, probably simpler :

```
$("#mdlGeneral > div").modal("show");
```

Comment: That's what I had originally, however, I wanted to be able to change the class in the outer div, which is why I put it into the JS and added another div to replace it. @ADyson was right in spotting my mistake. I was calling the div and not the modal div.

Comment: edited with both `addclass` stuff and the inner container `.show` method